# jQuery 'unique' not returning actual unique values in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, unique

I have seen similar posts on this but I cannot resolve my issue with the answers from other posts. I have the following function to return unique values from a large array:

```
self.availableActivies = ko.computed(function () {
   var activities = [];
   $.each(self.data(), function(i, s){
      activities.push(s.activities);
   });
   return $.unique(activities);
});
```

When I push s.activities to the 'activities' array, I have an array with about 30 repeated activities, but only 4 unique activities.

The last jQuery line returns exactly what I need in chrome, but I cannot figure out how to do this without jQuery so that it works in all browsers.

Comment: `if(jQuery.inArray(s.activities,activities) == -1){
    // the element is not in the array
activities.push(s.activities);
};` try this way

Comment: What is the data structure of items in `activities` array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `$.unique` works [with DOM](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) .

[image]
However it seems `activities` is another type of Array.

---

- Thus, try `$.unique(activities.sort());`
- Anyway ,we recommend to  Use  instead`$.inArray` & `$.grep` for an array like `activites` ,

  ```
    function customUnique(array) {
       return $.grep(array, function(el, index) {
          return index === $.inArray(el, array);
        });
     }
  ```

  Then :

  ```
   self.availableActivies = ko.computed(function () {
      var activities = [];
      $.each(self.data(), function(i, s){
          activities.push(s.activities);
      });
      return customUnique(activities);
    });
  ```

Comment: Thank you.  The $unique(activities.sort()); option worked just fine.  Thanks for your time.